# Angular select empty value

Tags: angularjs

I have an application for managing user roles. I have a bunch of users in an array `$scope.users`. The structure of a user object looks like that:

```
{
    name: "Larry",
    role: {
        id: 2,
        name: "Work"
        class: "role-work"
    },
    mustHaveRole: true
}
```

I also have a bunch of roles in an array `$scope.roles`. The structure of each role element is the same as each users `role` field.

I need to create a `<select>` element, which contains every role in `$scope.roles`. Each `<option>` element needs to have the class specified in its `class` field. The role, which has a matching `id` with the user's `role.id`, must be initialy selected. The `<select>` element must inherit it's class from surrently selected `<option>` element. For users, who have `mustHaveRole` set to `false`, there must also be a empty element which sets it's `role` field to `null`.

How can this be achieved? I feel like `ng-options` is not flexible enough, but when I create all the `<option>` elements with `ng-repeat`, Angular sometimes creates an extra empty `<option>` elementy, which should not be there-

Comment: You would have to repeat the options, however, adding classes to the options sounds like a not so good idea.

Comment: It might or might not be a good idea, but it necessary. Each role should have a background color depending on it's type, so they are easily distinguishable. As mentioned, `ng-repeat` sometimes creates an extra `<option>` element, that I don't need. How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

Assign  the `ng-model` with user role id

```
<div ng-controller="MyCntrl">
  <select ng-model="user.role.id" ng-options="v for v in roles">
  </select>
</div>

function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.roles= {   "type": "select", 
    "values": [ "Role 1", "Role 2", "Role 3", "Role 4"] 
  };
}
```

Check this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/wTRXZYEPrZJRizEltQ2g)

Comment: I still need to assign classes to options.